# Redirect to specific route by programming with Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In the app.routing:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [{
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },{
        path: '',
        component: AdminLayoutComponent,
        children: [{
            path: '',
            loadChildren: './moduleDashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
        },{
            path: 'client',
            loadChildren: './moduleCustomer/customer.module#CustomerModule'
        }]
];
```

In the CustomerRoutes :

```
export const CustomerRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
        children: [ {
            path: 'clil',
            component: CustomerListComponent
        },{
            path: 'clie',
            component: CustomerAddComponent
        },{
            path: 'clie/:customerReference',
            component: CustomerAddComponent         
        }]
    }];
```

On the component I have a button when I click on it I'd like be redirected to a specific path with an argument.

I tried these solutions

```
this.router.navigate(['client/clie/', 1900001])

this.router.navigate(['client/clie/', 1900001], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

but I'm all the time redirected to `/dashboard`instead `/client/clie/1900001`

any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: You have configured the route settings for the path '' <= which is your root path twice, it will always trigger the very first one in that array, in your case, that is the redirectTo: 'dashboard' configuration and everything else isn't even triggered, what exactly are you trying to do with the dashboard and the rest, or why is that redirect there at all?

Comment: To be honest it's a theme I bought I didn't change anything in the routing config. I just added some modules.I tried to remove some part but that's not work.

Comment: Try removing the `redirectTo` from App routes

Comment: @Rust I tried but now I get a blank page when I start the application

Answer (score 0):

Dashboard shouldn't be lazy loaded it's the initial page. You have to load some page to be lazy after.

```
    export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      }, 
      {
       path: 'dashboard',
       component: DashboardComponent
      }, 
      {
        path: '',
        component: AdminLayoutComponent,
        children: [{
            path: 'client',
            loadChildren: './moduleCustomer/customer.module#CustomerModule'
        }]
];
```

This may works. Try it. I didn't run this code personally by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [{
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },{
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: AdminLayoutComponent,
        children: [{
            path: '',
            loadChildren: './moduleDashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
        },{
            path: 'client',
            loadChildren: './moduleCustomer/customer.module#CustomerModule'
        }]
];
```

Comment: No I just see the menu but the component are not loaded. I get this error ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'client/clil' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'client/clil'. By default when I start the application I want to be on dashboard.

Comment: does it work going to `/dashboard/client` ? is that all the routes you have defined? send a link to where the theme you're using is coming from